# json array check if there does not need to insert in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, duplicates, local-storage

I need to check a JavaScript array to see if there are duplicate values ​​. What is the easiest way to do this ? I just need to check whether the values ​​already exist if there is not need to go into json array.

```js
function cek() {
    resi_or_code = document.getElementById('code_or_resi').value;
    resi = resi_or_code.split(',');
     if($.trim(resi_or_code) != ''){
      location.href = base_url + 'resi/' + encodeURIComponent(resi_or_code);
 
      }
      if (localStorage.daftar_data){
            daftar_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('daftar_data'));
            $("#riwayat").toggle();

      }
      else {
      daftar_data = [];
      }

    for (y in daftar_data){
        var q =  daftar_data[y].resis;
        for (x in resi){
        console.log(q); 
            if (q === resi[x]) 
            {   
            console.log('Value exist');

            }else{
            console.log('Value does not exist');
            daftar_data.push({'resis':resi[x]});
            localStorage.setItem('daftar_data', JSON.stringify(daftar_data));
            } 
        }
    }

   
}
```

Comment: same code for two different question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828082/remove-duplicate-input-value-using-javascript#37828082

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest way is to simply sort your array using [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). This will perform well and reduces you duplicate check to a simple for-loop that compares each value with its neighbor.

Solutions that attempt to avoid sorting will almost certainly scale very badly.

So to recap and show some code:

```
daftar_data.sort();
for (var index = 0; index < daftar_data.length - 1; index++)
{
  if (daftar_data[index] === daftar_data[index+1]) {
    // Found a duplicate
  }
}
```

If the natural sort order of the objects don't work for you, supply a function to the sort function, like so:

```
daftar_data.sort(function(a, b) {
  // return any value > 0 if a is greater, < 0 if b is greater 
  // and 0 if they are equal. 
});
```

Note that in this form, you can actually check for the duplicate in your compare function.

Comment: I couldn't see that, since you didn't submit your JSON. But actually, you assign an empty array on line 14, and you also use push(). So it looks like an array.

Comment: how your solution ?

Comment: My solution is to sort the array as described above. Then a simple for-loop finds the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question and code right, you basically have an array of objects where each object has key `resis`

If that is the case, below code might help

```
 var valueArray = ar.map(function(item) {
    return item.resis;
 })

 // To check for duplicate
 if(valueArray.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
     // Duplicates
 } else {
     // No duplicate
 }
```

In your case,
`ar` would be `daftar_data`. 
I am really not sure what your `value` is. is it `resi`?
Basically, you should try replacing your for loop with the above code.

Comment: So localStorage Already, there are data, I want to compare data in localStorage with the user input , if the user inputs an existing dilocalstorage not going to save

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: answers more details

Comment: You can help me help you by giving more details in the question. Could you give a sample of what `daftar_array` holds. Same for `resi_or_code`