# remove duplicate input value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make a history search based on user text input html, this code below works fine but it duplicates the same input. For instance :

1. The user type 'abcd' in input text and click the button.
2. the value 'abcd' store as history search.
3. When the user try to search the 'abcd' and click the button again, the history search adding 'abcd' as well, so it has 2 'abcd' value.

My js function:

```
function cek() {
   resi_or_code = document.getElementById('code_or_resi').value;
   resi = resi_or_code.split(',');
    if($.trim(resi_or_code) != ''){
     location.href = base_url + 'resi/' + encodeURIComponent(resi_or_code);

     }
     if (localStorage.daftar_data){
           daftar_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('daftar_data'));
           $("#riwayat").toggle();

     }
     else {
     daftar_data = [];
     }

   for (y in daftar_data){
       var q =  daftar_data[y].resis;
       for (x in resi){
       console.log(q); 
           if (q === resi[x]) 
           {   
           console.log('Value exist');

           }else{
           console.log('Value does not exist');
           daftar_data.push({'resis':resi[x]});
           localStorage.setItem('daftar_data', JSON.stringify(daftar_data));
           } 
       }
   }


}
```

What did I do wrong? Please help.

Comment: same code for two different question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828082/remove-duplicate-input-value-using-javascript#37828082

Comment: Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) are for **runnable** examples. Use the `{}` button for simple code blocks if they aren't runnable examples.

Comment: ok, thank you @T.J.Crowder